# Why cycle duplicates printf?

Tags: c

```
printf("How many instruments you want to enter? (max 7):");
scanf("%d", &num);

while (n <= num) {
    printf("Enter the name of %d instrument:\n", n);
    fgets(linha, 100, stdin);
    sscanf(linha, "%s", nome_inst);
    fprintf(fich_melodia, "%s\n", nome_inst);
    n++;
}
```

why do I have two duplicated printf of Enter the name of instrument in the output???

Comment: where do you declare `n`?

Comment: Can you make a stand-alone simple program that shows your problem? The above code is not compible and runnable. Most likely though, your condition in `while` is incorrect. What is `n` initially?

Comment: Well what do you think? Because you're running the loop twice, presumably! What are num and n...

Comment: Avoid mixing `scanf()` with `fgets()`.  The first call to `fgets()` is consuming the left-over `'\n'` from `scanf()`.  Also check `sscanf()` and `fgets()` results.

Comment: Post your whole code and state your problem clearly.

Answer (score 4):

The `scanf()` leaves an <kbd>ENTER</kbd> hanging in the input buffer.

The first time through the loop an empty line is processed.

Hint: read the number of instruments with `fgets()` and `strtol()`.